# ¿Cómo ver los datos en la casilla de selección?

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi código:

```
{assign var=cl_size value=","|explode:$data.cg_cloth_size}
        {$cl_size|@print_r}
        <div class="form-group" align="left" >

        <label for="cartsize">Select Size</label>

        <select class="form-control" style="width:150px;" name="cartsize" required>

        <option value="">Select Size</option>

        {foreach $records as $data}

        <option value="{$data.cg_cloth_size}" {$select_{$data.cg_cloth_size}} >{$data.cg_cloth_size}</option>

        {/foreach}

        </select>

        </div>
```

Quiero ver el registro en el cuadro de selección en esta forma: a b c

Pero el problema es esta vista de datos como a, b, c en este formulario en el cuadro de selección

Answer (score 3):

¿Podrías probar esto?

```
{foreach from=$records item=data}
  {$data}
{/foreach}
```